# Quadratic spline interpolation: original reference

Tags: reference-request, spline

I need a reference where quadratic spline interpolation with spline having additional knots lying *between* the provided reference points was introduced for the first time. Can anybody give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be the book "A Practical Guide to Splines" by Carl deBoor.

Or, you could search through deBoor's spline bibliography [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~deboor/bib/refsearch.cgi).

A couple of early works are:

W.J. Kammerer, G.W. Reddien, R.S. Varga; 
Quadratic interpolatory splines; 
Numer. Math., 22 (1974), pp. 241–259

M.J. Marsden; 
Quadratic spline interpolation; 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 80 (1974), pp. 903–906

Comment: Thank you. The Carl deBoor's book is much more readable than original papers but has a disadvantage that a reader must read it from the beginning in order to understand a chapter located somewhere in the middle...

Comment: Yes. In general, it's not easy to read. But it's worth the effort, in my opinion.